# Monotone-convergence-type theorem for indicator functions

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the measure space $(S,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ and functions $f,\{f_n\}\in\mathcal{L}^0$, and $f_n\rightarrow f$, a.e. When is the following true
$$
\lim_n \int 1_{|f_n-f|>\epsilon} \;d\mu = \int\lim_n 1_{|f_n-f|>\epsilon}\; d\mu.
$$
Can I invoke continuity of measure or a convergence theorem of some sort?

Comment: This generally fails when the measure space is not finite, due to the fact that the characteristic functions are not integrable. Take the Lebesgue measure on the real line and $f_{n}(x) = 1_{[n,\infty)}(x)$

Comment: @TheOscillator Thanks for the reply. So the statement is true when $\mu(S)<\infty$? Hence, I can use the fact that $\{|f_{n+1}-f|\} \subset \{|f_n-f|\}$?

Comment: Yes. In the finite measure space setting constants are integrable, hence it follows trivially from the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem (DCT).